# MongoDB IP Address BETWEEN Query

Tags: sql, mongodb, ip, pymongo, between

I am looking for the mongo equivalent to this SQL Query:

```
SELECT country
FROM geoip
WHERE
2921648058 BETWEEN start AND end
```

My MongoDB Documents look like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("52daefed0c78fc8c9085498d"),
        "country" : "DE",
        "end" : "16777471",
        "start" : "16777216"
}
```

The numbers are IP Adresses converted to int format. Unfortunately all searches regarding this only come up with the $gt and $lt operators, which aren't of much use in this case, because i don't want to retrieve documents with a certain field inside a range, but documents where a range provided the document itself fits a given number from the search. 

Going through all the records and evaluating the result in a script is not an option because of the massive size of the database.

Comment: I have read your question many times, but I can not figure out why you can not use $gt and $lt operators. "Start" have to be lower than your value and "end" higher than your value. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `$gte` and `$lte` operators do actually apply here; you just need to use separate operators for `start` and `end`:

```
ip = 2921648058;
db.geoip.find({'start': {'$lte': ip}, 'end': {'$gte': ip}})
```